# Datediff between two date colums without the weekends, add as EXTRA Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two date columns in my table. I want to add an extra column with the number of days between the two date fields without the weekends.

dbo.Date:

```
+------------+------------+-------------+
|   Date1    |   Date2    | DaysBetween |
+------------+------------+-------------+
| 2017-12-01 | 2017-12-31 |          21 |
+------------+------------+-------------+
```

So the weekends are excluded in this result.

Comment: I think you need to count weeks and days then exclude weekend from days.

Comment: What have you tried already and what was the result?

Comment: The way your question is worded it sounds like you want to add this as a computer column to the existing table. Is that what you are looking to do or calculate it somewhere else and insert the data?

Comment: Make a function to check each day between Date1 and Date2 use a loop, that will take some time to run but easy to do.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

By using [`CTE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql).

```
DECLARE @st_date date,
        @end_date date

SET @st_date = '12/01/2017'
SET @end_date = '12/31/2017'

;WITH dateCte
AS (SELECT
  @st_date AS [days]
UNION ALL
SELECT
  DATEADD(D, 1, [days]) [days]
FROM dateCte
WHERE [days] < @end_date)
SELECT
  @st_date Date1,
  @end_date Date2,
  COUNT(DATENAME(WEEKDAY, days)) [DaysBetween]
FROM dateCte
WHERE DATENAME(WEEKDAY, days) <> 'Saturday'
AND DATENAME(WEEKDAY, days) <> 'Sunday'
```